# Primefaces Save/Pass Filtered DataTable Results List

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable, render

Currently, I'm displaying image metadata successfully from my database using a datatable with sorting/filtering capabilities. Below my datatable I'm successfully displaying my images using a third party image coverflow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/). I'm using the same list to display both at this point. After I filter my data within my datatable I need to dynamically update my image list in my coverflow with the filtered datatable results.

What is the best way to do this using PrimeFaces? Would anyone be able to point me toward a working example?

Here is my code:

screenshotData.xhtml

```xml
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="scrshot" value="#{screenshots}" paginator="true" rows="8" 
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" widgetVar="dataTable" draggableColumns="true"
                 emptyMessage="No screenshot data found with given criteria"> 
          <f:facet name="header"> 
            <p:outputPanel> 
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:"/> 
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="dataTable.filter()" style="width:150px" /> 
            </p:outputPanel> 
          </f:facet>
          <p:column headerText="Time" sortBy="#{scrshot.time}" filterBy="#{scrshot.time}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{scrshot.time}" /> 
          </p:column> 
          <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{scrshot.id}" filterBy="#{scrshot.id}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{scrshot.id}" /> 
          </p:column> 
          <p:column headerText="User" sortBy="#{scrshot.user}" filterBy="#{scrshot.user}" filterMatchMode="startsWith"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{scrshot.user}" /> 
          </p:column>
          </p:dataTable>   
        </h:form>     
        <br/>
        <h:form>
          <p:outputPanel id="imgBlock" layout="block">
           <div class="ContentFlow"  style="width: 1400px; height: 500px" align="center">
            <div class="loadIndicator"><div class="indicator"></div></div>
            <div class="flow">
              <a4j:repeat var="img" value="#{screenshots}" rendered="true">
                 <div class="item">       
                     <img class="content" id="images" src="ImgServlet?id=#{img.id}" title="#{img.time}" draggable="true"/>
                     <div class="label">#{img.id}</div>
                  </div>
              </a4j:repeat>
             </div>         
           <div class="globalCaption"></div>
           <div class="scrollbar"><div class="slider"><div class="position"></div></div></div>
          </div>
         </p:outputPanel> 
       </h:form>   
...............
```

Screenshot.java

```java
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="imgTable", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
public class Screenshot implements Serializable, PhotoInterface {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   private String user;
   private Timestamp time;
-------- Getters/Setters ---------
```

ScreenshotListProducer.java

```java
@RequestScoped
public class ScreenshotListProducer {
   @Inject
   private EntityManager em;

   private List<Screenshot> screenshots;

   @Produces
   @Named
   public List<Screenshot> getScreenshots() {
      return screenshots;
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this an interesting question so I did some research. First I had a laugh finding [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23336). Then I stumbled upon [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17941). The answer appears to be:

Add this to the `<p:datatable>`:

```xml
<p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{bean.onFilter}" update = "@this"/>
```

In the bean:

```java
public Map<String, String> onFilter(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
       List<Screenshot> obj =   table.getFilteredData();

       // Do your stuff here

       Map<String, String>  filters = table.getFilters();
       return filters;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I implemented this and can display the filtered results in an outputPanel! Currently, I've been trying to display images of selected records within a datatable. I appear to have an issue with the ContentFlow implementation outside the scope of this question. You may look at that one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660247/display-db-images-using-contentflow-coverflow-illegalstateexception-error Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Good to hear that your making progress. If my answer answers the question you've asked, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, that's all the thanks I need ;-) Welcome to stackoverflow by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the all comments in this and an other questions.

I will share the solution whith PrimeFaces 5.1:

```
public Map<String, Object> onFilter(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("FILTRAMOS LA TABLA");
        DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
        List<Actual> obj = table.getFilteredValue();

        listaActivosFijosFiltrados = obj;

        if (obj != null) {
            System.out.println("filtered = " + obj.size());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No records found");
        }

        Map<String, Object> filters = table.getFilters();
        return filters;
    }
```